# post json directly to amazon s3 bucket from ionic/angular front end

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, ionic-framework, amazon-s3

I am struggling to figure out how, or if possible, I can post/put data into an aws s3 bucket from an angular/ionic application...

I have a mobile application that has two surveys, one for before using the product, second for after using the product... after both surveys I want to just dumb the data in an aws bucket. The amount of data is pretty small... about 50 surveys are expected each with basic text answers to ~20ish questions.

Does anyone have any idea how I can do this in ionic/angular or any front end? Do I need to convert it to a file somehow and then post that?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Which file type you want to store in AWS s3? e.g. text, csv ...

Comment: On top of above quetion, Have you tried https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer/ ?

Comment: if it has to be a file... it doesn't really matter I guess? just jsons or text files that have the data... it's a fairly small amount of data

Answer (score 1):

You can upload a JSON object directly to a bucket in s3. You don't have to upload it through a file, although I have no idea how to do it in Ionic/Angular, here is sample of how it is done in Node.

```
s3.putObject({Bucket: 'bucket_name',Key: 'my_products.json',Body: JSON.stringify(products), ContentType: "application/json"},function(err, data){console.log(JSON.stringify(err)+" "+JSON.stringify(data));});
```

Comment: I found this answer gave a good hint about what to dig into.  great tip about the S3 class of AWS SDK [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html) Here's Getting Started guide to AWS SDK -- [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/getting-started.html)